# Tried replacing a bedroom light/fan and I can’t get the switch to respond/shut it off

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan, light

Tried replacing a fan/light combo in a bedroom of a 1971 built home. This is my third install around the house. When I pulled the old fan off I found 7 wires (3 white bundled and soldered together, 3 black and what looks like a white bundled and soldered together), and all the grounds bundled and soldered. When I took the old motor out the black/white bundle fell apart. Tested each individual wire to find the hot and only one black had power. Proceeded to test it with a simple bulb fixture and I can get power to it, however cannot get it to turn off by using the switch. Switch only has a ground, a white and black going to it.

The current state of the wires:

[image: A photograph of the wiring inside the junction box]

Comment: Soldered? That's extremely unusual for a 1970s home. Normal would be wire nuts.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like a switch loop.

Should have a white connected to black(or all blacks except one), that will be the hot to the switch.

Then you should have a single black from the switch, that is the switch hot and goes to the fan black.

The fan white goes to the whites connected together.

The blacks connected together, one is the hot from the panel and two extra blacks go to other lights/receptacles to power them.  Same for the whites connected together.

Comment: This answer by crip659 explains the probable wiring arrangement. If the lamp is staying on independent of the switch, that means you have the line hot connected directly to the fan. What you want is the switched hot connected to the fan hot. The line hot (which you identified as the only hot) is supposed to go to one side of the switch and the other side of the switch (called the switched hot) is to be connected to the fan black hot). That way the switch will turn off the power to the fan. In this arrangement a white wire is used as a hot or a switched hot and is not a neutral.